# Increase Target Box and acquire Image info from Jquery-sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to increase the size of the target for the image drop zone so that when a user drags it, they can tell that's where they should drop and the page won't adjust randomly to the image being dropped and from that drop get the list of the images' order.  How would I approach making the target bigger and getting the info on the image?  The info on the image can be just the source name list.

**Edit: I want to drag an item into the box and it go up as the first and increase the target box's range so users can confidently drag into the box with the proper cue.**

```js
var order;
var adjustment;

var group = $("ol.simple_with_animation").sortable({
  group: 'simple_with_animation',
  pullPlaceholder: false,
  // animation on drop
  onDrop: function($item, container, _super) {

    var $clonedItem = $('<li/>').css({
      height: 0
    });
    $item.before($clonedItem);
    $clonedItem.animate({
      'height': $item.height()
    });

    $item.animate($clonedItem.position(), function() {
      $clonedItem.detach();
      _super($item, container);
    });
    var data = group.sortable("serialize").get();
    order = data[1];
    console.log(order);
  },

  // set $item relative to cursor position
  onDragStart: function($item, container, _super) {
    var offset = $item.offset(),
      pointer = container.rootGroup.pointer;

    adjustment = {
      left: pointer.left - offset.left,
      top: pointer.top - offset.top
    };

    _super($item, container);
  },
  onDrag: function($item, position) {
    $item.css({
      left: position.left - adjustment.left,
      top: position.top - adjustment.top
    });
  },
  serialize: function(parent, children, isContainer) {
    return isContainer ? children.join() : parent.text();
  },
  tolerance: 6,
  distance: 10
});
```

```css
body.dragging,
body.dragging * {
  cursor: move !important;
}

.dragged {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 2000;
}

ol.simple_with_animation li.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  /** More li styles **/
}

ol.simple_with_animation li.placeholder:before {
  position: absolute;
  /** Define arrowhead **/
}

#GamblerOrderSource,
#GamblerOrderTarget {
  min-height: 50px;
  margin: 0px 25px 10px 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
  display: inline-block;
}

#GamblerOrderSource {
  border: 2px dashed #f8e0b1 !important;
  background-color: #fefcf5 !important;
}

#GamblerOrderTarget {
  border: 2px dashed #add38d !important;
  background-color: #f6fbf4 !important;
}

#GamblerOrderSource li {
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
  border: 1px solid #fbeed5;
  color: #c09853;
}

#GamblerOrderTarget li {
  background-color: #ebf5e6;
  border: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
  color: #468847;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sortable/0.9.13/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>
<form id="orderform" method='POST'>
  <div id='GamblerOrderSource'>
    <ol class='simple_with_animation'>
  <li id="image_first"><img src="http://ec2-54-244-61-189.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com//static/DEAD.ICO"></li>
<li id="image_second"><img src="http://ec2-54-244-61-189.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com//static/DEAD.ICO"></li>
  <li id="image_third"><img src="http://ec2-54-244-61-189.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com//static/DEAD.ICO"></li>
<li id="image_fourth"><img src="http://ec2-54-244-61-189.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com//static/DEAD.ICO"></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div id='GamblerOrderTarget'>
    <ol class='simple_with_animation'>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Jquery-sortable I simply modified it to the following:

```
.dragged {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 2000;
}
ol.simple_with_animation li.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  /** More li styles **/
   font-size: 200%; /* or whatever */
}
```